# trouble configuring a relay editing torrc file on windows

Tags: configuration

I have added these lines to torrc file (as describled on Tor's site):

```
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname ididntedittheconfig
ContactInfo human@...
```

But after that i cannot start Tor anymore... the only way to start it again is remove the above lines from the torrc file.

Comment: `ExitPolicy reject *:*` You have mistyped?

Comment: As @RichardHorrocks wrote `--verify-config` is quite helpful. Could you provide us with the output of this option? It might give a hint what exactly went wrong here.

Comment: Ah. So before the edit by @JensKubieziel, I hadn't noticed that the `:` (colon) had been italicized in the original text of the question, meaning that the `*` characters - which *had* been included in his config - had been interpreted as mark-up by SE. When I ran the test noted in my answer, I missed out the `*` characters. I'll edit my answer once the OP has responded further.

Comment: @JensKubieziel everything he posted is fine *except* ExitPolicy syntax - so WTF an answer deletion was that? And - converting my answer with astersisks before and after ":" (colon) - you've removed it and made it read wrong. WTF, man?

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin You made the same mistake as the OP. If you put code into `backticks` it will show the asterisks, with asterisks only it will be treated as *italic* text.

Comment: @JensKubieziel not just backticks, but a "cite mode" preserves them also, like I did it in my answer - take a look. OP's mistake, IMHO - was a *mistype* in placing `Exitpolicy` instead of `ExitPolicy`

Comment: Hi @AlexeyVesnin - the keywords are case insensitive, so `Exitpolicy` and `ExitPolicy` are both valid. I think we'll need to wait for the OP to respond further before we can find out what's really happening.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks hmm, it was case-sensitive... Let's wait for more details, then.... Maybe rename Nickname? It can be a source-controlled

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the config that Tor is using by passing it the `--verify-config` flag on the command line:

```
tor --verify-config
```

This should help give you some idea as to which line is wrong.

Substituting your lines into my config file and running the above command shows that Alexey's answer is correct:

```
Apr 11 09:39:13.779 [warn] Couldn't parse line ":". Dropping
Apr 11 09:39:13.779 [warn] Malformed policy 'reject :'.
Apr 11 09:39:13.779 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Error in ExitPolicy entry.
```

Comment: Dea Richard, how do i pass the verify config flag? On which command line? Please note that i use windows...

Comment: Okay, on Windows you'll need to open the command line by running `cmd` in the Run box. (Is that what it's called?) Then you'll need to find the directory where `tor.exe` is stored, and start it with the flag: `C:\<path_to_exe>\tor.exe --verify-config`.